# Dijkstra's algo, visit binary tree depth-first order

Tags: binary-tree, dijkstra, depth-first-search

I am dealing with a binary tree, and I'm wondering how to weight edges in order to visit the binary tree in depth-first order.
  I know that I need to allocate less weight to edges leading to nodes I wanna visit first.
  But is there a relation with the depth of the node?
Cheers.

Comment: Why do you need it? Academical interest?

Comment: Yes, little question, I'm stuck on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like an excercise for a student. It is possible to search a binary tree depth first using Dijkstra's algorithm. There is indeed a relation between the edges and the depth of the tree:

```
             A
          1      4
       B             E
     1   2         1   2
   C       D     F      G
```

In the tree above the letters represent nodes and the numbers represent weighted edges. Dijkstra's algorithm will visit the nodes of this tree in a depth first order. In this specific case: in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Since Dijkstra algorithm computes mins between predecessors of each vertex, you will always have such a BFS behavior. For instance you start at the first know vertex `A`. No pred, value set to 0. You take all its successors, and for each of them, you test the distance and associated values of all predecessors. It’s somewhere like a BFS for me.